# fixing my php script unknown error

Tags: php, mysql, session, isset

im having problem my server upgraded from php4 to php5
can anyone help me understand the change i carnt get my head around it
ive broke the code down that need editing

```
session_start();
unset($l);
session_register($l);

/***********************************************************************

Check if user is logged on and display the appropriate page

************************************************************************/

if($page=="" or $page==" "){

header("Location: site_start.php");

}

if($page!="" and& $page!=" "){

if(!isset($l)){

include ("templates/template_header_main.php");

include ("templates/template_login_top.php");

include ("templates/template_$page.php");

include ("templates/template_footer_main.php"); }

else
```

the problem is with the isset and sessions register i know ive to change the
session_register($l) to $_SESSION['name']= $name;

but then how do i edit the isset to work with the new
$_SESSION['name']= $name; or how do i edit the $_SESSION['name']= $name; to work with the old isset
also
can you please explain to me here whats actually going on , im great
with .php and automated scripts but all i can think that $_session in
more of a command not a $var more of a session register command , if
this is so could someone share the $_session command list please
this has proper baffled my head all help is greatly welcome

thank you
autolinktrader

ALSO I FOUND THIS

```
// Fix for removed Session functions
function fix_session_register(){
function session_register(){
$args = func_get_args();
$_SESSION[$key]=$GLOBALS[$key];
}
}
function session_is_registered($key){
return isset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
function session_unregister($key){
unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

its ment to fix my error i believe but now i get this error

i just a white screen with this error

> Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'Europe/Moscow' for 'MSK/3.0/no DST' instead in
>   /home/autolink/public_html/domain1/index.php on line 48
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/autolink/public_html/donain1/index.php:48) in
>   /home/autolink/public_html/domain1/index.php on line 82

any help would be grateful

Comment: #1) The warning tells you what to do: Add `date_default_timezone_set()` with the timezone you want to use to the beginning of the php script.  #2) Because that warning is being output to your browser, the page will not redirect like your code requests. Clear up that warning, and the script will redirect as it should.

Comment: Also, `session_register` is deprecated as of PHP 5.4. Don't use it. And I'm not understanding what you are doing with the `$l` variable. You unset it and then try to use it all through your script.

Comment: Also, about your isset, just do `if (isset($name)) { $_SESSION['name']= $name; }`. However I hope that you don't have register globals on. Likely you want something like `$_POST['name']` or `$_GET['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

1- [session_register()](https://www.php.net/session_register):

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Use `$_SESSION['key']` instead, and remember start your page with [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

2- Set a Default Time zone:

[date.timezone in php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

[DateTime::setTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

[date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

[List of Supported Timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

3- [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL and return TRUE or FALSE